# Salesforce document archival

Tags: salesforce

On the Salesforce front end application documents are uploaded, where I have a requirement to archive documents when no longer required. Is there a tool or process in Salesforce to archive documents, if so would appreciate any details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try one of the below options:

U can simply mark the document as archived. Although technically still will be counted towards your storage wont appear to the users.

Else u can also try integrating with google drive and through which u can archive documents.

You can also look at this blog where many AppExchange tools has been mentioned which supports your requirement.